# ClickOnce code signing failure on one app but not others

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing

I code sign apps when I publish with Clickonce. I use a password protected xxx.pfx file. I use this same file to publish multiple different apps with ClickOnce. However, on this one particular app, when I publish I get the following error:

> Cannot import the following key file: {file name}.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_7234A89B766DF5A7

I have tried to use the sn tool to reinstall the certificate but it says the certificate already exists. I tried deleting the container with the sn -d VS_KEY_7234A89B766DF5A7 but it says the container doesn't exist.

So, the exact same xxx.pfx file can be used to publish some of my applications but not this one.

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix worked for me though I can't really say why. There is an MSBuild project property AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile. Some of my ClickOnce projects have this property in the PropertyGroup, others did not. All the projects however were able to sign the app during the ClickOnce publication process.

With respect to the app that failed code signing during publication, I removed AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile from the xxx.csproj and then tried to publish the app with code signing and it was successful.

Not sure if this is reproducible (I hope not to see this issue again). But, ClickOnce publication seemed to work without this property.

I would also add the the code signing certificate was installed with its private key into the certificate store and was exposed as a xxx.pfx file. I was unable to use the certificate from either the store or the file until after I removed this property.